# Paste yanked block with `p` gets mixed with lines below

Tags: vim, copy, paste

If I copy 3 lines with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd> and then go to another window and paste with <kbd>p</kbd>, the lines get mixed.

How can I paste the yanked block as new lines, so the old lines move below instead of get mixed with the pasted ones?

Comment: v > shift $ > 2j > y, then paste with p in target window

Answer (score 2):

When you press `Ctrl-V` in normal mode, you are switched into the V-BLOCK mode where the text will be copied **blockwise** (with relatively fixed position).

@PeterRincker gave a very easy way in the comments section, you can put the yanked block **linewise** by:

```
:put
```

> `:[line]pu[t] [x]`    Put the text [from register x] after [line] (default current line).
>   This always works |linewise|, thus this command can be used to put a yanked block as new lines.

---

Below is my original answer, which takes much more steps.

A not very neat yet practical way to paste it **linewise**:

- `:new` to create a new buffer
- `p` to paste
- `Shift+V+G` to select all text
- `y` to copy

And now you get the normal form of the copied text.

Comment: You can force a paste to be linewise via `:put` with out any of these intermediate steps.

Answer (score 1):

There are three different *visual modes*; by using `<C-V>`, you've used *blockwise visual mode*; cp. `:help blockwise-visual`. Such yanks are stored as a "floating" block of text that is inserted inside existing surrounding characters (as you've discovered). If you want to copy-and-paste full lines, the easiest would be to yank in linewise mode (i.e. use `V` instead of `<C-V>`, or skip visual mode altogether and use the shorter `[N]yy` instead).

That doesn't work if you want to **select partial** lines, but **paste as full separate lines**. For that, the mode of the register contents need to be changed. I needed to "cast" register contents into a certain (characterwise / linewise / blockwise) mode so often, I wrote the [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) for it. It provides `gcp`, `glp`, etc. alternatives to the built-in paste commands that force a certain mode (and by now several more variations on this theme, like pasting with joined by commas or queried characters).

With it, you can just use `glp` / `glP` to paste after / before the current line, regardless of how you've yanked the text.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I also found that `Ctrl+v` go down as many lines as I want and then `Ctrl+yy` or `Ctrl+Y` and then the `p` works as expected.

Comment: I don't get it. By default, `Ctrl-Y` just scroll up the window. How do you use it to copy text?