# Vim block paste inline or new line

Tags: vim

I have this problem where I try to yank/cut and paste a block of text with Vim and it has inconsistent behavior.

What happens is this:

In this text bellow, I what to cut the middle column and paste after the third. So I block-select (ctrl-v) the text, cut it (x), take the cursor to the end of the third column (now 2nd) and paste (p)

```
A 1 a
B 2 b 
C 3 c
D 4 d
```

Sometimes Vim does it right and the result is this:

```
A a 1
B b 2
C c 3
D d 4
```

and some times, the result is this:

```
A a
1
2
3
4
B b
C c
D d
```

I need to control that behavior instead of being a hostage of it... How do I control this behavior?

Comment: Are you copying line returns when you do your block select? It might help if you do ctrl+V go down the middle line use ctrl+I then add a space, exit and paste.

Comment: If you use `<C-v>` all the time, the behavior should be consistent (and it is for me). To be sure, you could check `:echo getregtype('')` prior to pasting, it should start with `^V`.

Comment: Sorry... I said yank the text and gave a example cutting the text...

Comment: It seems that I am not the only one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126723/paste-yanked-block-with-p-gets-mixed-with-lines-below/
This guy is trying not to paste inline by default.
And I am trying not to paste with a new line by default.

Comment: I have a similar problem except I don't see inconsistent behaviour - my visual blocks are always pasted as new lines (your second example) whereas I want to be able to paste the block on existing lines to rearrange columns of text (like your first example). Presumably there's some option or alternative paste command that switches this behaviour - just need to find what it is...

Answer (score 3):

Well, one answer is the UnconditionalPaste plugin (https://vimawesome.com/plugin/unconditionalpaste)

with a 'gbp' you paste a block inline (I remapped to [LEADER]pb)

it works...

Comment: I strongly suggest you stay alway from using many plugins until you have a basic understanding of how vim works.

Comment: too late, I use dozens of plugins... :D I don't like to use long commands do do advanced things on vim... I like plugins though.

Comment: Massive kudos to you, dude. Found this by googling. Straight to the point and does exactly what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

I  recommend you  reading  the  help topics  for  visual selection,
`:h visual.txt`. The  section on `visual-operators` and  its notes might
be particularly useful. Selection behavior is pretty consistent and easy
to understand  though. If  you cut  or copy something,  expect it  to be
placed in the same mode: characters, lines, or blocks.

> I  what to  cut the  middl ecolumn  and paste  after the  third. So  I
>   block-select (ctrl-v)  the text, yank it  (y), take the cursor  to the
>   end of the third column (now 2nd) and paste (p)

That's not  how you  should do it.  To "cut" the  middle column,  as you
describe, you came to use `x` and not `y`. Yanking will just copy it and
leave it there.

[image: Blockwise selection demo]

Regarding  your last  example where  content  was pasted  in a  linewise
fashion, that  should not happen when  using `p` since it  conserves the
blockwise information.  The only possible  explanation that comes  to my
mind is  you deleted  a  column and used `:put`  to paste it.  That will
convert it to a linewise paste. Alternatively:

- You yanked something likewise (say from `V`) and you are trying to
  paste it blockwise
- Your example does not translate well your problem
- There is some sort of plugin or configuration affecting this
- Random unknown keys were slammed in the process

Comment: I do know that vim has loads of operators, and I am sure that there is some combination of operators that do inline block pasting inline/newline consistently but that is not exactly what I asked... I just want to yank and paste blocks consistently, which I currently can not. Probably that is  because that I kit a command accidentally (looking at another window) and messed the default settings. I just want to control that behavior.

Comment: I swear I am not becoming crazy... I have done the same thing on Vim and observed different behaviors. Unless... I do am crazy...
The problem is that it takes a very long time to observe that change on behavior, which is very hard to diagnose...

Comment: @MtCS Well, if it is difficult to you, imagine for us here on the other side. You are not being clear.

Comment: sorry if I was not clear. 

I did tried to use $p after cutting, but it didn't work for me

Comment: If you repeat the same keystrokes I used here with the same text and it does not work, then the only explanation is that there is a plugin or configuration messing up with your commands. Try again starting Vim with `vim -u NONE` to skip initializations.